Zero Flag Not Set After Addition/Subtraction on 8086 Emulator (DOS) Using TD
I'm working on a simple assembly program for the 8086 emulator (DOS) using Turbo Debugger (TD). My task is to set the Zero Flag (ZF) to 1 using addition/Subtraction. However, no matter what I try, the Zero Flag does not get set. Here's the code snippet I'm trying:
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h

DATASEG

CODESEG
start:
    mov al, 4Bh
    mov ah, 4Bh
    sub al, ah


exit:
    mov ax, 4C00h   
    int 21h         

END start

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
I was Expecting to see the Zero flag becomes 1 like in my text book:
Text Book Example
Here is what i see after executing the program:
TD final State after executing
I tried Debugging it using F8/F7 which runs the program line by line or step by step respectively and it seems like the TD skips the first line of my program or something , I'm not quite sure if this is the case.
Would be happy if you guys have any ideas.
Thanks!

Make sure you are running the binary created from the source. Switch to disassembly view to see what code you are actually running.

I'm pretty sure im running the binary created from the source , here's is how i did it:                tasm /zi name.asm  --> tlink /v name.obj --> td name

Make sure you don't both have a name.com and a name.exe. Switch to disassembly and post screenshot.

AX should also equal 4B00 at this point, so yeah, the code definitely hasn't been executed as shown. Which lines does the debugger step through, and do you see the registers change as they should?

CF, OF, and PF are also wrong.

You are not running the binary that matches the source.
We can see the machine code in the second column in your screenshot.
Disassembling gives:
B39C mov bl,0x9c
B79C mov bh,0x9c
02DF add bl,bh

This also matches the fact that bx is highlighted in the register window and it has value 9c38 and the flags match.

Thank you so much , I think i figured it out !

You guys are the best ! https://imgur.com/a/llGV0UB
